# How to keep users from accessing anything outside application in .net

Tags: .net, security, kiosk

Are there any common designs or best practices for keeping users confined to your .net application (unless of course they have access to get out of the application)?

Comment: This is a pretty vague question... what do you mean by "confined" and "get out of"?

Comment: For example, you are an employer with a McDonald's franchise and your employees check customers out using a POS application.  You don't want the employees to be able to play solitaire... or anything worse.

Comment: @JaredShaver As far as the employee is concerned, the computer doesn't know how to do anything other than take orders.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is "kiosk application", Brandon. Think ATM, or ticket dispenser.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Thanks, maybe I can get some better google results now :)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I didn't really think about that because a kiosk app is typically for the customer to use and doesn't have the complexity of a POS app, but yeah I guess the same concepts are going to apply for confining the user to the app.

Comment: Yep. Either you lock 'em in, or you don't.

Comment: You'll find that the technical parts of the kiosk is more in setting up the OS and less about changing how you would write your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very dependent on which kind of application you are using, but the term to feed google is "Kiosk-Mode".